# Can you use non-standard characters for creating a Bitcoin Brain Wallet?

Tags: brain-wallet

Can you use non-standard characters to create a bitcoin brain wallet? Ex. Chinese characters, ascii characters using the numberpad with ALT key.

Is there downsides to this?

Answer (score 1):

In short words: yes.

But you should know the algorithm how brainwallets are generated. Nobody guarantees that brainwallets on different services are generated with the same algorithm.

Comment: So would a hash of the following two chinese characters: 中國 have a collision with any of the combinations of all the standard usa keyboard character combinations?

Comment: I think that brainwallets should convert string to utf-8. Check it yourself

Comment: how do i check if it converts it to utf-8 ?

Comment: just tried the following: 台北  is the equivalent of &#21488;&#21271; ... as tested here: http://www.pinyin.info/tools/converter/chars2uninumbers.html -- but when used to generate an address via bitaddress its different.

Comment: This is html-encoding, not utf-8